# Optimistic synchronization of replicated objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, synchronization, websocket, optimistic

I'm programming a browser application (html5+websockets+css3+js preferred) that enables users to concurrently access (read, write) attributes of the same object. To create a real-time experience I'd like to use optimistic synchronization. I read about Timewarp and Trailing State algorithms and I wonder if there is a javascript library, which already implements these or similar algorithms.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340176/solution-for-optimistic-object-replication-between-java-server-and-browser-client), but unfortunately it was not answered yet. XSTM only supports pessimistic synchronization as it seems.

Do you have any idea for me?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a realtime HTML5 web browser application now too. Maybe my choice of weaponry could inspire you...who knows, so I am using:
Frontend:

- [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) -it takes care of displaying data which I send to every connected client in JSON(view models), you can easily subscribe to changes in the client data and push the changes back to server, though I am having problems displaying pages with knockoutjs on mobile browsers
- on serverside I run custom made server based on [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck)
- Since JSON is my favourite data format, I ditched SQL databases in favour of [RavenDB][2], which stores data almost exactly as they are sent via websocket protocol and also it is pretty quick

Comment: KnockoutJS and Fleck are nice tools, but I don't see how they solve the synchronization issue at all. What I learned since I filed the questions is that the community is in favor of OT based algorithms. Still there is work to be done to port the rather scientific efforts about graph- and tree-based OT into the web world. However, that would possibly do the trick.